# One parse query being called and one not in cellForItemAtIndexPath method

Tags: arrays, parse-platform, uiimageview, swift2, ios9

In my cell for item at index path method I'm attempting to populate an array of UIImageViews using parse data. The creator image view populates just fine but the second "if let" for the attendee array isn't getting called at all (I'm pretty sure the code would work although it's a bit tricky and I'm not 100% sure but I want it to at least get called first)

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    //sets up cell

    let cell : EventCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventCell

    //adds attend action

    cell.attendButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


    //queries parse for events 

    let event = events?[indexPath.row]

    event?.eventImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

        if let data = data, image = UIImage(data: data) {

            cell.eventBackgroundImage.image = image
            cell.eventTitleLabel.text = event?.eventTitle

            //gets profile picture of events creator 

            if let eventCreator = event?.objectForKey("user") as? PFUser {
                if let creatorImage = eventCreator.objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile {
                        creatorImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

                        cell.creatorImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                    })
                }
            }



            //gets profile pictures for image view array on back of cell

            if let attendeeArray = event?.objectForKey("attendees") as? [PFUser] {

                for var index = 0; index < attendeeArray.count; ++index {
                    let profileImageView = cell.imageViewArray[index]
                    let usr : PFUser = (attendeeArray[index] as PFUser?)!

                    //                        if let picture = usr.objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile {

                    usr.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if let picture = object!.objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile {
                            picture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
                                profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                            })
                        }
                    })


                }

            }


            //sets correct category for cell image

            if event?.category == "" {
                cell.categoryImageView.image = nil
            }

            if event?.category == "The Arts" {
                cell.categoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Comedy")
            }

            if event?.category == "The Outdoors" {
                cell.categoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Landscape")
            }

            if event?.category == "Other" {
                cell.categoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Dice")
            }

            if event?.category == "Sports" {
                cell.categoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Exercise")
            }

            if event?.category == "Academics" {
                cell.categoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: "University")
            }

            if event?.category == "Science" {
                cell.categoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Physics")
            }

            if event?.category == "Entertainment" {
                cell.categoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Bowling")
            }

            if event?.category == "Food & Drinks" {
                cell.categoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Food")
            }

            if let date = event?.eventDate {
                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

                cell.eventDescriptionLabel.text = event?.eventDescription
                cell.eventDateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
            }
        }
    })

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20

    //not sure if necessary

//        let subviews : NSArray = cell.contentView.subviews
//        
//        for view in subviews {
//            view.removeFromSuperview()
//        }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: The query logic should be moved out of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Create a `loadEvents` function which performs the query. In the completion block of the query, update the array of events to be set as the data source to the collection view and refresh the view. As the view is being refreshed, `cellForItemAtIndexPath` will automatically be called to populate the collection view with the new data.

Comment: I do query in the view did load method but in order to access the index path I also put the above code in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method. I just don't know why the first 'if let' is getting called but the second is not. The creator image of the image view shows up just fine.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the complete structure of your Parse class. The code seems fine so my guess would be that there is either a typo in `objectForKey` or `event` does not contain the expected data. Try using some `print` statements to see what the values inside of `event` to further diagnose the issue